# Make page view controller only animate in certain area

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I want the page view controller to not show the black bottom and top bars while animating. 
Ive tried making the pageviewcontrollers frame smaller, but I just end up with a smaller picture and more black space on top and bottom.

Here's what it looks like now

[image]

Btw, The images I'm showing are using UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Thanks so much for any help. 
Please let me know if theres any other information you need.

Thank you